# How to Delete lines that contain more than three dots in a email?

Tags: linux

How do we delete the lines which have more than three dots in an email address?
How do we do this with sed command?

Eg:

```
fgtc21_pk@yahoo.com
bhchemitex@chemitex.com
hjcindysun48@hotmail.com
hhconsult_sa.jan.2020@yahoo.com
s.ing.song.lan.g.ju.n.55.l@gmail.com
VB.t.o.t.all.y.f.it.s.19.99@gmail.com
a.lice.i.n.wonde.r.lnd.2.1.f@gmail.com
```

I want the following lines with multiple Dots (3 or more dots )deleted from the file.

```
s.ing.song.lan.g.ju.n.55.l@gmail.com
VB.t.o.t.all.y.f.it.s.19.99@gmail.com
a.lice.i.n.wonde.r.lnd.2.1.f@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed '/^\(.*\..*\)\{3,\}@/d'
```

Match from the beginning of the line zero or more any characters, then a dot, then zero or more any characters, 3 or more times, then match a `@` sign. Delete matching lines.

Comment: Thank you.. This works great. What if, I want to cut those lines with multiple Dots (3 or more dots ) and copy to a new file and delete it from the main file, how do we do that?

Comment: You mean, you want to just run sed twice? Once with `sed -n '/ ... /p' > file_with_dots_only` to print matching lines and `sed '/..../d` to delete lines that match the pattern. You could use sed `r` command, but unless the file isn't really big, I wouldn't use it anyway.

Comment: I ran some more test and found that the above command you mentioned recognizes every DOT in the line... It is recoznizing DOTS after @ sign too, which it shoudnt actually. For example, even this is shown in the result: ryisan@Sariyer.Cc.itu.Edu.tr Can you help me modify your above command in such a way that only the LEFT side of @ it counts the Multiple DOTS more than 3 and IGNORE the DOTS after the charater @ to right.